# Asynchronous update of the component after properties are changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use `getDerivedStateFromProps()` to update component after properties are changed, but it doesn't work. I have read somewhere that this function is synchronous - if it's the case, what would be good way to do this?

```
static async getDerivedStateFromProps(props, prevState) {
  if (props) {
    let students = [];

    await this.getStudents({ class: props.classId })
      .then(res => students = res.result)
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });

    return {
      students: students
    };
  }

  return null;
}

getStudents = async (params) => {
  const response = await fetch(apiRequestString.studentsByClass(params));
  const body = await response.json();

  if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

  return body;
}
```

From the `Network` tab I can notice that `getStudents()` method is not called at all because there is no request to the route.

This is the initial state of the element:

```
// State of the parent element; 'classId' has initial value of null
<Students classId={this.state.classId} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had an older version of React. I updated version of `react` and `react-dom` to `^16.3.1` and everything works well now.

P.S. I also had to use `componentDidUpdate()` since `getDerivedStateFromProps()` is synchronous function.

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.props.classId.length && prevProps.classId !== this.props.classId) {
    let students = [];

    await this.getStudents({ class: this.props.classId })
      .then(res => students = res.result)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    this.setState({
      students: students
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a static method. It has no access to Object instance with `this`. You could fix it by making `getStudents` static too and then use by referencing a class:

```
static async getStudents(params) {
  ...
}

await Students.getStudents({ class: props.classId })
```

Comment: Thanks! However, for some reason, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Nikola can you make sure for example with `console.log` that it gets to `await Students.getStudents...` ?

Comment: Just checked, it doesn't get to that part. I checked with React Dev Tools and I'm completely sure that property has been changed.